# Como fazer minha função len() retornar o tamanho de std::string, vetor e const char *?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Minha função `len()` em C++ pode retornar o tamanho de `std::string` e de `std::vector<std::string>` porém não pode retornar o tamanho de `const char *`, pois para isso ou eu teria que usar `strlen()` ou converter `const char *` para `std::string` para usar o método `size`. Não consegui mudar o controle de fluxo com o `if` para verificar o tipo de dado entrado e redirecionar para o tratamento como seria fácil em linguagens interpretadas.

Como editar essa função para retornar o tamanho tanto de `std::string` e `std::vector<std::string>` como também de `const char *` de uma maneira bastante atraente?

```
// Função len()
template < typename T >
int len( T args )
{
    return args.size();
}

std::string a = "Ola Mundo!";
const char * b = "Ola Mundo!";
std::vector<std::string> c = {"Ola", "Mundo", "!"};

std::cout << len(a) << "\n"; // Retorna 10.
std::cout << len(b) << "\n"; // error: request for member 'size' in 'args', which is of non-class type 'const char*'
std::cout << len(c) << "\n"; // Retorna 3.
```

Comment: Você está usando C++17? Se está porque não colocou na pergunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em adição à resposta do Maniero, você também pode utilizar [std::is_same](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) juntamente com constexpr para validar as operações de tipo específico (C++17). Isso pode ajudar a evitar duplicação de código caso você passe a ter várias especializaçoes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
int len(T args) {

    if constexpr (is_same_v<T, const char*>) {
        return strlen(args);
    } else {
        return args.size(); 
    }
}

int main() {
    string a = "Ola Mundo!";
    const char *b = "Ola Mundo!";
    vector<string> c = {"Ola", "Mundo", "!"};
    cout << len(a) << "\n";
    cout << len(b) << "\n";
    cout << len(c) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Excelente! Agradeço a resposta do Maniero, mas essa é a resposta perfeita para o que estou estava procurando. Era justamente um if com esse comportamento que eu precisava. O if constexpr será essencial no controle de fluxo dos meus programas.

Answer (score 3):

Não é `if` que você deve fazer, é especialização (um conceito bem mais avançado que não parece que seja o caso de aprender agora). Assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
int len(T args) { return args.size(); }
template<>
int len(const char *args) { return strlen(args); }

int main() {
    string a = "Ola Mundo!";
    const char *b = "Ola Mundo!";
    vector<string> c = {"Ola", "Mundo", "!"};
    cout << len(a) << "\n";
    cout << len(b) << "\n";
    cout << len(c) << "\n";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/kaSVMn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/SpecializationString). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Template/SpecializationString.cpp).

A pergunta originalmente não falava que poderia usar C++17, pelo contrário ela dizia sobre C++11 ou C++14, com o C++17 minha resposta seria:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
int len(T args) {
    if constexpr (is_same_v<T, const char*>) return strlen(args);
    else return args.size(); 
}

int main() {
    string a = "Ola Mundo!";
    const char *b = "Ola Mundo!";
    vector<string> c = {"Ola", "Mundo", "!"};
    cout << len(a) << "\n";
    cout << len(b) << "\n";
    cout << len(c) << "\n";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **GDB Online**](https://onlinegdb.com/B1cCG4SJS). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Template/IfSameType.cpp).

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou direitinho. Assim não precisarei me importar se o texto é string ou const char * na hora de pegar o tamanho.